# Snowflake: Your account has been locked. To continue using snowflake, please contact support

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are getting this error message on every single snowflake account in our organization. We are unable to contact support because we cannot login anywhere. We are on GCP-backed snowflake. Is this a known issue?

Comment: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge

Comment: @MikeWalton - we are unable to create a case because we cannot login. It's not a very good system lol.

Comment: Try support@snowflake.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you email support@snowflake.com it automatically files a support case for you, so that should be used to file a support ticket when you are unable to even login.

It should be noted that this is impossible to find on their website, and it is impossible to reach a human for mission critical errors like this. Be warned if you want to move any of your critical systems onto snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your account is locked due to non-payment? You should contact Snowflake Support so they can check why the account is locked.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it was indeed locked due to non-payment and we received exactly 0 emails notifying us about this. Snowflake support is abysmal.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue in January 2023. My client called and informed me that all developers and admins received "Your account is locked". After opening an urgent case over the phone and then online, I finally heard back via email that their collections team was going to assist. So it was an issue with my client's credit card which was recently renewed. We had no notice - no emails or alerts about a billing problem. Awful.